# iOS 7 - UIPickerView curved components

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview

I just want to know how you can disable this "curved effect" of the components of an UIPickerView in iOS 7?

This is what I get with an UIPickerView with 3 components:
[image: One UIPickerView with 3 Components - curved effect on non-selected rows of component 1 and 3.]

And this is what I wanna have:

In this screen I used 3 UIPickerViews with only 1 component to simulate that
[image: Three UIPickerViews with 1 Component each - no curved effect on non-selected rows.]

TL;DR:

I want the non-selected rows centered and not curved as you can see in screen#2, but still using one UIPickerView only.

Is it possible? If yes let me know how, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to create your own custom control :(

According to Apple's UIKit UI Catalog:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPickerView.html

> **Appearance of Picker Views (Programmatic)**
>
> You cannot customize the appearance of picker views.

As far as I know you can't even change the background colour of a UIPickerView under iOS7!

Answer (score 0):

You can center and select a row by the following code:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return pickerView.frame.width / noOfComponent - (pickerView.frame.width / noOfComponent * noOfComponent)
}
```